# Using Gaia Passbands with $L_\nu$ coordinates

Tags: astrophysics, spectroscopy

I am trying to find the coordinates of my bundles of gas on the gaia ($G,G_{bp}−G_{rp}$) hr diagram. I have its spectrum in luminosity $\nu L_\nu$ coordinates. Thus far, my attempts have mainly been to integrate to find the passband ($x=G,G_{bp},G_{rp}$) luminosity
$$L_x = \int B_x \frac{\nu L_\nu}{\nu}d\nu = \int B_x L_\nu d\nu$$
Where $B_x$ is the response, and using D = 10 parsecs to find the flux
$$F_x = \frac{L_x}{4\pi D^2}$$
Then, using the zero points $Z_x$ to get the magnitude
$$G_x = -2.5 \log F_x + Z_x$$
However, this results in my gas being extremely dim in the visible, G comes out to be as large as 100 in some cases. Am I using the passbands incorrectly? Theoretically, as a crude approximation, the Bremsstrahlung (free-free) radiation alone should be within a few orders of magnitude of white dwarfs, completely disagreeing with these results.

My array of $\nu L_\nu$ is given in erg/s, so I begin by multiplying my array by $10^{-7}$ to get it as joules/s, and I take 10 parsecs in meters to have SI units, as I read that the gaia magnitudes are computed with SI units.

As a test, I approximated Vega as a blackbody and from its flux computed its G coordinates. However, they were far off from zero, which makes me think that something is wrong in my process.